# use from has action but no call to route

Tags: laravel

when i click to button nothing happened.

code in html

```
<from action="{{route('add_to_card')}}" method="post">
                                    {{csrf_field()}}
                                    @method('PATCH')
                                    <label>Quantity:</label>
                                    <input name="qty" type="text" value="1"/>
                                     <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{$product_by_details->product_id}}">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-fefault cart">
                                    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                                    Add to cart
                                    </button>
                                </from>
```

code in route

```
route::post('/add-to-cart','CartController@add_to_cart')->name('add_to_card');
```

code in controller

```
 public function add_to_cart(Request $request)
{
    echo"1";
}
```

Even when i echo something

Comment: all code in html
https://github.com/cq522138/test_1/blob/master/product_details.blade.php

Answer (score 1):

In the line 20 of your file ([Here](https://github.com/cq522138/test_1/blob/master/product_details.blade.php#L20))

Change <**fr**om> to <**fo**rm> , you had typo error .
Do it for closig tag on line 30.

Answer (score 0):

First of all please visit this [site](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions) to have an idea on the naming conventions in laravel. This will help a lot and prevent future errors and to make your application more optimized.

Now for my answer, nothing happens when you click the button because you are using the tag `<from>` instead of `<form>`.
All  you have to do is change the `<from>` tag to `<form>` tag.